# Questions based on opinion

Tags: discussion, off-topic

How can I post questions to know the community opinion about a theme, in 'A or B' style, without get 'off-toppic'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opinion-based questions and answers are always off-topic on Stack Exchange.

However, questions about a site itself (or the SE Network) may be allowed with opinions on its child meta or Meta.

Also, [as *PolyGeo* has answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299653/350567), *chat* is available for opinions.

If you're really looking for opinions about something, go to Reddit or Quora.

Comment: why the negative votes?

Comment: Umm... Maybe people here are clear that *primarily opinion-based* questions are off-topic here so it's useless to ask about how to gather opinions.

Answer (score 4):

Some chat rooms are happy to have opinions asked for.

Just be sure to check the protocols of a particular chat room by visiting the site's Meta, asking the chat room users what's OK to discuss there, or by observing a chat room for a while before posting.

You need a reputation of 20 on the Main site before you can post in one of its chat rooms.

Comment: Good I forgot chat.